# JavaScripting .sort()'ing a Multidimensional Array of Scores to Order the Player Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array

I understand the JS .sort() function well enough, and I have a loose grasp on multidimensional arrays, but I'm a little stuck. Here's what I've got:

```
var player1 = ["bob", 20];
var player2 = ["jon", 40];
var player3 = ["tim", 10];
var scores = [player1[1], player2[1], player3[1]];

scores.sort(sortfunc);

function sortfunc(a,b){
  return a - b;
}

alert(scores);
```

Obviously this sorts the scores correctly, but what I want is to order the player names appropriately in the alert() based on their score, e.g. tim, bob, jon. I'm not necessarily looking for someone to post the answer straight-up, but a little hint in the right direction wouldn't hurt!

Also, is there a better (i.e. cleaner, simpler, what have you) way of doing this with jQuery?  I know it doesn't particularly matter, but I'm just wondering what it would look like in jQuery, too.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Let me clarify: you'd like to sort the players along with the names right?

Comment: I suppose sorting the players would work as well, yes. I just want to be able to order the names properly with who is in first, second, third, etc., no matter how it's accomplished.

Comment: I've added an answer, please see if that fits your requirements :)

Comment: Instead of using jQuery to do this you might want to take a look at underscore.js it has a bunch of neat functions to deal with javascript's built in data structures as well as some functional helpers. [heres the sortBy documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the whole array in `scores` and your sortFunc extract the first element:

http://jsfiddle.net/PS2wS/

```
var player1 = ["bob", 20];
var player2 = ["jon", 40];
var player3 = ["tim", 10];
var scores = [player1, player2, player3];

scores.sort(sortfunc);

function sortfunc(a,b){
  return a[1] - b[1];
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely what I wanted. I see what you did by passing the entire array and then sorting just by the score. Unfortunately, I utterly fail to understand why passing the entire array works the way it does, so I guess my grasp on multidimensional arrays is tenuous at best. Regardless, thank you for solving it.

Comment: I'll be awarding you the answer in 3 minutes when it allows me. =)

Comment: @daveycroqet the callback in the first argument of sort() takes two parameter, which is the direct first level members of the array `sort()` is called upon. So in my answer, a and b would be player1, player2 and player3. We are telling it how to return the order by doing a substraction of the first element of playerX, which is the score.